# Доступ ко всем репозиториям Github

Tags: github, github-api

Имеется моя учетка с 6 репозиториями.  В данный момент умею получать доступ только к каждому отдельно.
Можно ли как-то получить "объединенный" доступ ко всем репозиториям? Ну типа зашел на свою учетку и все. Вот тебе все твои репозитории? Буду благодарен любому ответу по **существу**. Сам загугить решение не смог.

Comment: Несмогли загуглить - напишите! иногда такой подход помогает =)

Answer (score 0):

Вся информация по репозиториям пользователя:

```
https://api.github.com/users/{OWNER}/repos
```

Информация по апи в целом:

https://developer.github.com/v3/